# Shell Script running individually but not producing correct results as a crontab job

Tags: hive, cron, hdfs, sh, hadoop2

I need to implement a use case, where I need to update hive table with newest file which comes in the a folder in hdfs from any source system. I am not using sqoop here.

I am supposed to receive updated file periodically from source system into a particular HDFS location (say /tmp/emp.csv). I have created a managed/internal table in hive and loaded the data into it manually for the very first time. 
Hence my latest employee table (created in hive, having warehouse at default location - /user/hive/warehouse) will be having all data present in emp.csv file.

Now as soon as new emp.csv file comes in HDFS location /tmp/emp.csv, I have written a shell script which will delete existing /user/hive/warehouse/employee/emp.csv file and replace it with latest file, Hence I could see latest employee data through hive query.

my script is like

```
#!/bin/bash
file_date=`hadoop fs -ls /tmp/emp.csv | awk '{print $6" "$7}'`
echo "file_date="$file_date

log_file_date="$(cat hist_lof_time.txt)"
echo "log_file_date="$log_file_date
if [ "$file_date" != "$log_file_date" ]; then
                echo "file data not match with log date"
        if [ -z "$log_file_date" ]; then
              echo "inside log date edit loop"
              echo $file_date > hist_lof_time.txt
    fi

        rm /opt/emp.csv
        hadoop fs -get /tmp/emp.csv /opt/

        hadoop fs -get /user/hive/warehouse/employee/emp.csv /opt/bkp/    
        hadoop fs -rm /user/hive/warehouse/employee/emp.csv

        hadoop fs -put /tmp/emp.csv /user/hive/warehouse/employee/
        echo $file_date > hist_lof_time.txt
    else
      echo "file is same so not processing further"
 fi
```

Now this scripts works fine when I run it as a shell script on console but as soon as I add it as my crontab job, it doesn't picks up the hdfs file time and time from hist_lof_time.txt file. Hence time always remains the same and job never runs for any new file update in HDFS.

I am running this cronjob in every 3 minutes

```
*/3 * * * * /opt/myscript.sh >>/opt/myscriptout.txt
```

Could anyone please help me with any pointer, where and what I am doing wrong here? Any quick help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Bhupesh

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the issue which I was facing.

Actually when I was running the script individually, it was able to pick hadoop shell commands [used in script] where as when I was trying to run this script as cron job, it was there not able to pick Hadoop home [bin]. Hence was not running any of the hadoop command used in that script.

Hence I first tried locating where my hadoop is using $which hadoop. then provided absolute path of hadoop/hdfs commands whereever required.
For example:

```
file_date=`/opt/hadoop-2.6.4/bin/hadoop fs -ls /tmp/emp.csv | awk '{print $6" "$7}'`
```

and it worked perfectly then after.